# Adding product thumbail and image programmaticly on wordpress/woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently i have been trying to add a thumbnail and image gallery to a specific product programaticly (obtained from url), using a custom script. Adding all the fields and meta-fields needed was achived, but adding the product image and thumbnail, has proven to be not so easy. I've developed the following code for the purpose, but i'am not so sure about it's correctness:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$product_array_obtained=array(array(
            'Multimedia' => array
                (
                    'Link0' => 'https://www.someimage1.com/image0.jpg',
                   'Link1'=>'https://www.someimage.com/image.jpg'
                )
));
$post_id=1112;
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($product_array_obtained);$i++){
$image_list_id="";
    if(sizeof($product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia'])>1){
    for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']);$j++){       //Generate image id string
        if($j==0){
            $image = media_sideload_image( $product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']['Link'.'$j'],$post_id, "$product_array_obtained[$i]['Titulo]"."$j", 'id' );                 //Add Thumbnail
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $image );
        }else{                                                                                                                                                              //Add rest to gallery
        $image_list_id = $image_list_id . media_sideload_image($product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']['Link'.'$j'],$post_id, "$product_array_obtained[$i]['Titulo]"."$j", 'id' ) . ',';
        } 
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id,'_product_image_gallery',$image_list_id);                   //Add remaiming images to gallery
    }else{
        $image = media_sideload_image( $product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']['Link'.'$j'],$post_id, "$product_array_obtained[$i]['Titulo]"."$j", 'id' );                     //Only add a thumbnail
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $image );
    }
}
```

Running this part of the sript allways trows an wordpress error: "A critical error occured on this site".

Any ideas on how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not pay attention to the little things. I corrected for you

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$product_array_obtained=array(array(
'Multimedia' => array
    (
        'Link0' => 'https://msa.biawp.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/beanie-2-100x100.jpg',
        'Link1'=> 'https://msa.biawp.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/beanie-with-logo-1-324x324.jpg'
    )
));
$post_id=1112;
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($product_array_obtained);$i++){
$image_list_id="";
    if(sizeof($product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia'])>1){
    for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']);$j++){       //Generate image id string
        if($j==0){
            $image = media_sideload_image( $product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']['Link'.$j],$post_id, "$product_array_obtained[$i]['Titulo']"."$j", 'id' );                 //Add Thumbnail
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $image );
        }else{                                                                                                                                                              //Add rest to gallery
            $image_list_id = $image_list_id . media_sideload_image($product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']['Link'.$j],$post_id, "$product_array_obtained[$i]['Titulo']"."$j", 'id' ) . ',';
        } 
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id,'_product_image_gallery',$image_list_id);                   //Add remaiming images to gallery
    }else{
        $image = media_sideload_image( $product_array_obtained[$i]['Multimedia']['Link'.$j],$post_id, "$product_array_obtained[$i]['Titulo']"."$i", 'id' );                     //Only add a thumbnail
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $image );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for he help, but still receiving the same error : ""A critical error occured on this site""

Comment: Managed to solve it, a index in the multimedia name was wrong, jumped from link0 to link 2, i had noticed it yesterday but forgot to edit in my local code. Thx for the help